# How to create installer for docker and electron together?

Tags: docker, installation, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I have an electron app that calls some APIs on my docker image.
Now I want to publish my application so 
How can I make an installer that installs Docker, pulls the docker image and install the electron app for the user?

Comment: This means the all end users need to install docker but this is not a right away.

Comment: Not only docker. you build your own image so they must add your image too.

Comment: @tpikachu What would you suggest to achieve such similar thing?

Comment: Why don't we build an isolated API service? Again, forcing install docker from the installer is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's good idea.
If you customer decides to use your app on 'Windows 10 Home', he will fail, because docker requires Pro version.